# String array replaced on instance isn't reflected

Tags: go

I have an instance of a struct that has an array field. When a goroutine replaces the array on the instance, all the other handles to that instance still have the original array. Why is this? What should I change so that the instance of `Container` below will reflect the change made on the goroutine?

A simple example is also reflected here: https://play.golang.org/p/dXVKN6o8aP

```
func Create() Container {
    instance := *&Container{
        values: []string{"initial value"},
    }
    go func() {
        instance.values = []string{"modified value"}
        fmt.Print("values updated")
    }()
    return instance
}

func main() {
    instance := Create()
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("%[1]v", instance.values)
    //prints "initial value", but I expected "modified value"
}
```

Comment: There are no "handles" (pointers) to `Container` -- you're returning the struct by value, not a pointer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using the slice's value. You return the value of the slice which is returned to `main` by copy. Goroutine then executes and updates the original value. Make the following changes:

```
func Create() *Container { // return a pointer to container

    // instance is now initialized and points to a Container value
    // (i.e. instance is of type *Container)
    instance := &Container{
        values: []string{"initial value"},
    }
    go func() {
        instance.values = []string{"modified value"}
        fmt.Print("values updated")
    }()
    return instance
}
```

Now that main has a pointer to the above `instance`, modifications done by goroutine will be visible.

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/AKwUZfTu0s

Also, to create a new value, you can directly use the type's name:

```
instance := Container{ // instance is of type Container
    // ...
}
```

And to create and initialize a pointer of a type, use:

```
instance := &Container{ // instance is of type *Container
    // ...
}
```

Doing something like below is redundant:

```
instance := *&Container{ // instance is of type Container. Same as first declaration
    // ...
}
```